# Deserializing a bitflag enum in C# with Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, enums, bitflags

I have a unity project. Using the stock json tools at my disposal, i'm trying to deserialize an enum that uses bit flags (ie something like)

```
[Flags]
enum Terrain 
{
  NORMAL = 0,
  FOREST = 1,
  SWAMP = 2,
  CAVE = 4 
}
```

In json it's something like **CityTerrain: "FOREST"**, however it seems that the deserialization doesn't like human readable string enums (it wants an integer i assume) which is especially troubling for me in the case of bit flags when i want to be able to combine flags, ie. **FOREST|CAVE**.

XML handled bitflag enums fine out of the box. Why does json, the superior format, seem to struggle with it so badly? Should i be making an enum wrapper for handling the deserialization of this? No matter what i do, i feel like my solution will be clunky and i will dislike it.

Ultimately it needs to be human readable and i won't accept a "solution" where my bitflag enum has to be represented as 5 in json. The entire point of this exercise is that it needs to be human readable but still deserializable.

Comment: _"Why does json, the superior format, seem to struggle with it so badly?"_ - .NET enums are first and foremost a numeric type.  Libraries such as JSON.NET and System.Text.Json allow you to create `JsonConverter` classes that can handle conversions between JSON representations and their .NET models. For string enum values, this is `StringEnumConverter` for JSON.NET and `JsonStringEnumConverter` for `System.Text.Json`. I don't know if Unity has something similar with its `JsonUtility`. Even so, I think you'd still need a custom converter for the case of bitflag -> string.

Comment: `Enum.Parse` can handle `"Forest, Cave"`, which might translate over to the default json parsing rules. Otherwise you'd need a custom converter.

Comment: If you do not want to create a custom converter I would consider packing/unpacking your value to a `List<Terrain>` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### For `Newtonsoft.Json`

you can use a [`StringEnumConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm) and pass it along into

```
var converter = new StringEnumConverter();
    
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(example, Formatting.Indented, converter);
```

and (actually optional apparently)

```
var example = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(json, converter);
```

in my test for deserializing it seems to also work with only

```
var example = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(json);
```

---

#### For `System.Text.Json`

you can use the equivalent [`JsonStringEnumConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter) and pass it via the options like e.g.

```
// IncludeFields depends on whether your type uses fields or properties
// by default System.Text.Json only considers properties
// so to reflect the behavior of Newtonsoft I enabled also fields
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true,  IncludeFields = true };
options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(example, options);
```

and

```
var example = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Example>(json, options);
```

---

[.Net Fiddle for both above](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5WEw2a)

**Note** (also applies to `JsonUtility` below): Both basically go through `ToString` and `Enum.Parse` so in the json it will read e.g.

```
"FOREST, SWAMP"
```

if for some reason you really want `FOREST|SWAMP` instead you will have to implement your own custom [`JsonConverter` (Newtonsoft)](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) or accordingly [`JsonConverter` (System.Text.Json)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to).

Basically using the same and do something like (pseudo code)

```
// When serializing Terrain -> string
var enumString = value.ToString().Replace(", ", "|");
```

and

```
// When deserializing string -> Terrain
var enumValue = (Terrain)Enum.Parse(enumString.Replace("|", ", "));
```

---

#### For built-in `JsonUtility`

afaik there is unfortunately nothing similar. You instead have to overwrite the serialization of the entire class like e.g.

```
public class Example : ISerializationCallbackReceiver
{
    public string Name;
    
    [NonSerialized]
    public Terrain Terrain;
    
    public int SomeVlaue;

    [SerializeField]
    private string terrain;
    
    
    public void OnBeforeSerialize()
    {
        terrain = Terrain.ToString();
    }

    public void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        Terrain = (Terrain)Enum.Parse(typeof(Terrain), terrain);
    }
}
```

**NOTE**:

- Have in mind though that this will also affect the way it is displayed in the Inspector => You might then want to implement a custom Inspector to basically "revert" the display and draw it as an enum flag field again.
- You also will have to repeat this for each and every type that contains a `Terrain` and shall be json serialized